# Remote PowerShell, find last 5 user logins

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am attempting to view the last 5 login events on an Enterprise machine as an Admin after a security event. I do initial investigations and am trying to find a way to quickly spit out a list of potential, 'suspects'.

I have been able to generate output that lists the logfile but under account name where you would generally see *\Domain\username* I only get the output, "SYSTEM" or similar.

If I had recently remoted into the machine it will pull my *\Domain\Username* and display it no problem.

Ideally I would like to make a script that pulls the logon events from a machine on the network with a list of who logged in recently and when.

This is what I have so far:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName security -InstanceId 4624 -ComputerName $_Computer -Newest 5 | Export-Csv C:\Users\username\Documents\filename
```

Answer (score 2):

this uses the far faster `Get-WinEvent` cmdlet & the `-FilterHashtable` parameter to both speed things up a tad and to add more selectors. you may want to remove some of the filters - this was written quite some time ago for another project. [*grin*]

```
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

# there REALLY otta be a way to get this list programmatically
$LogonTypeTable = [ordered]@{
    '0' = 'System'
    '2' = 'Interactive'
    '3' = 'Network'
    '4' = 'Batch'
    '5' = 'Service'
    '6' = 'Proxy'
    '7' = 'Unlock'
    '8' = 'NetworkCleartext'
    '9' = 'NewCredentials'
    '10' = 'RemoteInteractive'
    '11' = 'CachedInteractive'
    '12' = 'CachedRemoteInteractive'
    '13' = 'CachedUnlock'
    }
$EventLevelTable = [ordered]@{
    LogAlways = 0
    Critical = 1
    Error = 2
    Warning = 3
    Informational = 4
    Verbose = 5
    }


$WantedLogonTypes = @(2, 3, 10, 11)
$AgeInDays = 15
$StartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$AgeInDays)

$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$GWE_FilterHashTable = @{
    Logname = 'Security'
    ID = 4624
    StartTime = $StartDate
    #Level  = 2
    }
$GWE_Params = @{
    FilterHashtable = $GWE_FilterHashTable
    ComputerName = $ComputerName
    MaxEvents = 100
    }
$RawLogonEventList = Get-WinEvent @GWE_Params

$LogonEventList = foreach ($RLEL_Item in $RawLogonEventList)
    {
    $LogonTypeID = $RLEL_Item.Properties[8].Value
    if ($LogonTypeID -in $WantedLogonTypes)
        {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            LogName = $RLEL_Item.LogName
            TimeCreated = $RLEL_Item.TimeCreated
            UserName = $RLEL_Item.Properties[5].Value
            LogonTypeID = $LogonTypeID
            LogonTypeName = $LogonTypeTable[$LogonTypeID.ToString()]
            }
        }
    }

$NewestLogonPerUser = $LogonEventList |
    Sort-Object -Property UserName |
    Group-Object -Property UserName |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Count -gt 1)
            {
            $_.Group[0]
            }
            else
            {
            $_.Group
            }
        }

$NewestLogonPerUser
```

current output on my system ...

```
LogName       : Security
TimeCreated   : 2019-01-24 1:50:44 PM
UserName      : ANONYMOUS LOGON
LogonTypeID   : 3
LogonTypeName : Network

LogName       : Security
TimeCreated   : 2019-01-24 1:50:50 PM
UserName      : [MyUserName]
LogonTypeID   : 2
LogonTypeName : Interactive
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I'll be sure to update when I try this out on my next shift (Thursday)

Comment: @Robert - you are most welcome! glad to help a bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

I've been fiddling with this too and also decided to use the `Get-WinEvent` cmdlet for this, because unfortunately, using `Get-EventLog` the info you want is all in the `.Message` item and that is a localized string..

My approach is a little different than [Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey)'s answer as I get the info from the underlying XML like this:

```
#logon types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ntsecapi/ne-ntsecapi-_security_logon_type#constants
$logonTypes = 'System','Undefined','Interactive','Network','Batch','Service','Proxy','Unlock',
              'NetworkCleartext','NewCredentials','RemoteInteractive','CachedInteractive',
              'CachedRemoteInteractive','CachedUnlock'

$dataItems = @{
    SubjectUserSid            = 0                                                                                                                                                  
    SubjectUserName           = 1                                                                                                                                                  
    SubjectDomainName         = 2                                                                                                                                                  
    SubjectLogonId            = 3                                                                                                                                                  
    TargetUserSid             = 4                                                                                                                                                  
    TargetUserName            = 5                                                                                                                                                  
    TargetDomainName          = 6                                                                                                                                                  
    TargetLogonId             = 7                                                                                                                                                  
    LogonType                 = 8                                                                                                                                                  
    LogonProcessName          = 9                                                                                                                                                  
    AuthenticationPackageName = 10                                                                                                                                                 
    WorkstationName           = 11                                                                                                                                                 
    LogonGuid                 = 12                                                                                                                                                 
    TransmittedServices       = 13                                                                                                                                                 
    LmPackageName             = 14                                                                                                                                                 
    KeyLength                 = 15                                                                                                                                                 
    ProcessId                 = 16                                                                                                                                                 
    ProcessName               = 17                                                                                                                                                 
    IpAddress                 = 18                                                                                                                                                 
    IpPort                    = 19 
}

$result = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Security";Id=4624} -MaxEvents 100 | ForEach-Object {
    # convert the event to XML and grab the Event node
    $eventXml = ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event

    # get the 'TargetDomainName' value and check it does not start with 'NT AUTHORITY'
    $domain = $eventXml.EventData.Data[$dataItems['TargetDomainName']].'#text'
    if ($domain -ne 'NT AUTHORITY' ) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Domain    = $domain
            UserName  = $eventXml.EventData.Data[$dataItems['TargetUserName']].'#text'
            UserSID   = $eventXml.EventData.Data[$dataItems['TargetUserSid']].'#text'
            LogonType = $logonTypes[[int]$eventXml.EventData.Data[$dataItems['LogonType']].'#text'] 
            Date      = [DateTime]$eventXml.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime
            Computer  = $eventXml.System.Computer
        }
    }
}

$result | Sort-Object Date -Descending | Group-Object -Property UserName  | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Count -gt 1) { $_.Group[0] } else { $_.Group } 
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

On my machine the output looks like

```
Domain   UserName    UserSID                                      LogonType   Date               Computer
------   --------    -------                                      ---------   ----               --------
MyDomain MyUserName  S-1-5-21-487608883-1237982911-748711624-1000 Interactive 27-1-2019 20:36:45 MyComputer
MyDomain SomeoneElse S-1-5-21-487608883-1237982911-748765431-1013 Interactive 27-1-2019 18:36:45 MyComputer
```