# Get-ADComputer Lastlogondate / Lastlogon

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm currently asking myself if it is possible to determine the last logon time of any user of a computer object which is connected to an active directory?

I need to find out when any user was logged onto a specific computer which is still online, communicating with the domain but was not in use in the last X days by any user.

I've already tried the following queries:

```
get-adcomputer $computername -Properties lastlogon | select 
@{Name="lastLogon";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.'lastLogon')}}
```

AND

```
get-adcomputer za31testvmrobin -Properties lastlogondate
```

I'm expecting the timestamp of the last logondate of a user on a computer object.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Is lastlogon an attribute that does not replicate? If so, you'd have to query all domain controllers per object for the most accurate information.

Comment: my understanding of the `.LastLogon` property is that it is the last time the _object_ logged into AD - and has no connection whatever to the last USER to logon from the computer. ///// you can get the last logged on user from this win7 registry item >>> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI` <<< i think the exact name of the key has changed in win10, but it should be similar.

Comment: The registry entry is a nice thing to know, but it does not display the logontime of the last logged on user.. And that's what I need.

Comment: There are Event IDs logged for logon activity (e.g. [Event ID 528](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=528), [Event ID 4624](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4624), etc) , but I think you need to enable logon auditing for this to work, so not useful for current systems, but might help in future.

Comment: @Robin - if you want to respond to a person in the comments ... use the `@` followed by their username. ///// it looks like `boxdog` has a way to get what you want. the successful logon id is showing up on my old win7 setup, so i suspect it is enabled by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote PowerShell, find last 5 user logins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385710/remote-powershell-find-last-5-user-logins)

Answer (score 0):

I somehow figured it out with help from @boxdog . Thanks for that.

Here is the Powershell Code in one line:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceId 4624 -ComputerName $computer | 
`where {$_.Message -match "Kontoname:       USERNAME" -and 
`$_.Message -match "Anmeldetyp:         2" }  | select -First 1)
```

Kontoname = Accountname
Anmeldetyp = Logontype (2 means interactive from console with keyboard & mouse)
The tabulator is needed. You can also use wildcards like an asterisk.

I could not find an easier way to get it working. Therefor I had to use the comparison operator "match" to find a string with which I could search within the Message property of the Eventlog.

Unfortunately searching takes some time. Via remote it takes up to 5 minutes each computer which is quiet unsatisfying.
Maybe someone has another solution which is faster or knows a way to work parallel, actually I don't really know how to do that, because I'm getting content with

```
get-content c:\data\input.txt
```

Thanks in advance