# Powershell: How to extract login information from Windows security event log?

Tags: powershell

How can I use Powershell to read and extract information from a window security log ?

I would like to have "Logon Type", "Security ID", "Workstation Name" and "Source Network Address" in output file.

I could find much information about how Powershell can get contents from event logs.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the event xml?  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2013/08/28/powershell-get-winevent-xml-madness-getting-details-from-event-logs/

Comment: See: [`Get-Winevent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote PowerShell, find last 5 user logins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385710/remote-powershell-find-last-5-user-logins)

Comment: @js2010 yes, this is what i am looking for. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the job:

```
$result = Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceId 4624 |
   ForEach-Object {
     [PSCustomObject]@{
     Time = $_.TimeGenerated
     Machine = $_.ReplacementStrings[6]
     User = $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
     Access = $_.ReplacementStrings[10]
     SourceAddr = $_.ReplacementStrings[18]
     }
   }

$result | Select-Object Time, Machine, User, Access, SourceAddr |  Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path .\Access_Log.csv
```

Note:
If it is launched on a domain controller the "Machine" variable will show the domain name while the User variable will show both user accesses and computer accesses

Comment: this info is useful to know the ReplacementStrings order  https://livebook.manning.com/book/powershell-deep-dives/chapter-6/37

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the event xml?   https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2013/08/28/powershell-get-winevent-xml-madness-getting-details-from-event-logs/